# Selenium automate a flash website (No elements available in console)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Am not able to fetch the elements (username,password) using selenium for the following website http://mls.realist.com/index.jsp

Comment: You probably won't be able to use selenium's WebElement features in this case. However, you may be able to do some naive automation by sending arbitrary keyboard strokes and clicking by coordinates.

Comment: Selenium manipulates elements in the browser DOM. A Flash plugin (or most plugins actually) is an external application that runs outside of the browser's DOM. You will need to use a different tool, such as GenieOS, Sikuli, AutoIT, Robot, ...